# Migracion: Ya existe un objeto llamado 'ActivoTipo' en la base de datos

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, identity, migracion

Estoy trabajando con el enfoque (si es que se puede llamar así)  Database First, ya tengo una base de datos creada y estoy intentando agregar identity a mi proyecto y a mi base de datos.

Ejecuto los siguientes comandos, uno para agregar la migración y el otro para aplicar los cambios a la base de datos.

```
dotnet ef migrations add "nombreDeLaMigracion"
dotnet ef update database
```

Cuando ejecuto el update, la consola me dice que está intentando crear la base de datos, ya que me da un error de una tabla que ya existe, ó eso lo que logro entender.

Me pueden orientar como trabajar con migraciones teniendo una base de datos existente?

Osea, si yo agrego una migración por primera vez, está se construye en funcion a la base de datos actual no?. no deberia ejecutar ninguna instrucción SQL o una representación de una consulta SQL, que permita la creacion de tablas ya existentes, ya que cada vez que ejecute el `dotnet ef update database` va a realizar este proceso.

No logro entender como trabajar con migraciones en una base de datos existente.

En que estoy herrado?, **me pueden orientar por favor!**

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [Inventario].[ActivoTipo] (
          [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
          [Nombre] varchar(101) NOT NULL,
          [FechaCreacion] datetime NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
          CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivoTipo] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Inventario].[ActivoTipo] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Nombre] varchar(101) NOT NULL,
    [FechaCreacion] datetime NULL DEFAULT ((getdate())),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivoTipo] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'ActivoTipo' in the database.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)       
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, 
Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)        
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:44b05e0d-9dc3-4e46-8e3d-089e8f921b35
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'ActivoTipo' in the database.
```

Comment: Si es la primera migracion va a intentar crear todos los objetos de la BD, si tu BD ya tiene tablas va a tronar

Comment: @JorgeLuis no sabia. Me puedes orientar que deberia hacer por favor

Comment: Supongo que lo primero que hiciste fue la BD, luego creaste el modelo en c#, luego la migracion y luego intentaste hacer el update verdad?, lo que yo haria es hacer un respaldo de la bd y luego borrar todas las tablas de esta y luego hacer el update y ya no deberia de tener problemas

Comment: @JorgeLuis Si, primero cree la BD, luego aplique el comando `scaffold` a la base de datos, está me generó los modelos y el archivo DbContext, luego aplique las migraciones. Pero no puedo borrar las tablas son muchas y ya tienen mucha data.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces una migracion crea una tabla en sql llamada __EFMigrationsHistory con esta sabe en que migracion va, lo que puedes hace es crear la tabla he insertar el dato de tu migración asi se va a "saltar" la primera migración

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory](
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MigrationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Lo que no estoy seguro es que va en ProductVersion porque en mi caso pone 6.0.7 que es mi versión de EF y estaba viendo otros ejemplos donde les pone otra cosa diferente a la versión, lo que puedes hacer es crear otra bd vacia y hacerle el update para ver que te pone.

INSERT INTO __EFMigrationsHistory(MigrationId, ProductVersion) VALUES('EL NOMBRE QUE LE PUSISTE A TU MIGRACION como esta en el archivo .cs', '')

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]